# Google OAuth signin fail on Chrome (not private session)

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm playing with the Google OAuth process and I encountered a strange issue with Google Chrome on IOS (v60.0.3112.89). On a classic navigation, what seems to be a "native Android panel" pop-up for the signin process (screenshot 1). After following the steps, it close and I'm stuck on a blank page and the url didn't changed (screenshot 2). On the other hand, in private navigation I have another OAuth Signin process and everything works fine (screenshot 3).

Everything works fine on desktop version (even on phone emulation). Works well on Safari Mobile.

I'm using a php backend redirection which is exactly the same for every clients.

Did someone ever had this issue?

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

[image: screenshot 3]